# IDE to SATA convertor Motherboard Issue

Tags: motherboard, sata, dvd-burning, pata

I bought new motherboard **Intel DH67GD** which has not IDE interface to attach the DVD writer.
It has 2 SATA with 6Gb/s, 3 SATA with 3Gb/s and 1 e-SATA with 3GB/s. [Mmobo specs link](http://www.intel.in/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dh67gd.html).

How can I connect my old LG DVD Writer (IDE interface)?

Will an IDE to SATA Connector work?

If yes then how to connect that DVD writer with IDE-SATA converter?

Comment: You are best to install an [ide pci/pci-e card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&N=-1&isNodeId=1&Description=pci+ide+card&x=0&y=0), connect your ide devices to that. pci cards are more compatible than adapters that connect to the back of the drive.

Answer (score 2):

1. Set the drive as Master (use a jumper for the pins, with text like "CS", "MA, "SL" or similar (Cable Select, Master, Slave)
2. Attach the [IDE to SATA adapter](http://www.cooldrives.com/lib/cooldrives/ide-drive-to-sata-adapter-plug-image-2.jpg) to the drive
3. Connect a SATA cable between the mobo SATA and the adapter SATA jack
4. Attach a power cable for the drive

It should work now, but it seems that some adapters and mobo combinations will not work with 100 % certainty.

**Edit:**

[Setting the jumper](http://www.pcstats.com/articleimages/200504/hddinstall_jump.jpg)

Comment: Can you give visual link ?

Comment: I added images to the post now

Comment: Yes, that's how it is.